# Origin of "shaliach mitzvah" money

Tags: sources-mekorot, minhag, tzedakah-charity, travel

Before someone goes on a trip, there is a custom to give that person a dollar to give to tzedakah when they arrive at their destination. I have heard that the reason for this is that no harm comes to a person who is on his or her way to do a mitzvah. What is the origin of this custom? Additionally, what is the source for the claim that a person on their way to do a mitzvah will not be harmed?

Comment: When someone's going to E"Y, there's an idea that one can send tzedokoh there, which has a bigger schar than in chu"l

Comment: צדקה תציל ממות"?